# How to wrap this value?

Tags: iphone

Example: I have a **scale between 1 and 7**. When I get a value like 8, I want it to be wrapped on that scale so it's converted to 1. More examples:

- 1 results in 1
- 5 results in 5
- 7 results in 7
- 8 results in 1
- 9 results in 2
- 10 results in 3
- 11 results in 4
- 12 results in 5
- 13 results in 6
- 14 results in 7
- 15 results in 1
- 16 results in 2

and so on.

Is there a method or useful C-function to do that? Something tells me I just need a modulo. It's 42°C in my room. My brain is like soap.

Comment: update: 42°, with air condition on 100% cooling power!! it's a glass house!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int b = ((a-1) % 7) + 1;`

Check using Excel, of all things!

Yes it's **HOT** today.. arrgh!

Comment: Too darned hot, although % 7 it's only 5°C.

Answer (score 2):

Try `((number - 1) % 7) + 1`.